# Is there the upper limit of the number of rollback in MySQL5.1 with InnoDB?

Tags: mysql

I do data management with InnoDB of MySQL5.1 and use transaction when I perform INSERT, UPDATE for plural tables. 
I sometimes brought myself to the incidentally, but will there be the method that how much data number knows whether rollback of protectionism is possible when I carry out rollback of protectionism on a transaction start point in time when INSERT processing failed?

Still I do not think that rollback of protectionism is possible with several hundred cases, several thousand cases without any restriction, but I want to grasp the thing which seems to be still some aim and think that I have you advise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is limited by the `max_binlog_cache_size` variable. If you are altering more data than this, then you'll get an error and the transaction will be automatically be rolled back.

In practical terms, on a 64bit computer you're going to run out of RAM and swap before the default of 16PB kicks in.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_cache_size